# PHP & HTTP authentication - get login and password with filter_input

Tags: php, http-authentication

I am trying to retrieve user login and password from HTTP authentication in PHP, using filter_input, but I get nulls for both PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW. I made a test:

```
$phpAuthUserFV = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_AUTH_USER');
// gives null

$phpAuthUser = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
// gives the user login entered

$remoteAddr = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REMOTE_ADDR');
// gives the remote address

$phpSelf = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF');
// gives the PHP_SELF value
```

Tested with PHP 5.5.5 and 5.3.3.

Am I missing something? I am just wondering, why filter_input fails for these two $_SERVER keys, but works with other.

Comment: Look at this comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#77307

Comment: @Ramesh, I am using PHP as module, but tried the code from the comment anyways. It seems that also REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT and REQUEST_TIME are inaccessible - and they are the last keys, after PHP_SELF

Comment: There is already a related bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61497

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this does not directly answer your question - since there seems to be something buggy going on - a decent workaround would be:

```
$phpAuthUser = filter_var($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
```

Comment: Well, this works, but it requires checking if the variable exists or using @ to avoid notices.

Comment: Please dont use @. Just do: `$phpAuthUser = ( isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ? filter_var($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) : null);`  "@" is the root of all evil..

Answer (score 2):

PHP_AUTH_USER is user auth properties so it will never retrieve without $_SERVER var.

Comment: `filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, , 'PHP_AUTH_USER');` should actually get the value from the $_SERVER var and additionally filter it with the default filter. This is what the question is about.

Comment: But for PHP_AUTH_SERVER it will not call it from the $_SERVER because it consider it as Authentic parameter and skip it in filter_input

Comment: To me that seems like a flaw in `filter_input()` then. It strikes me as odd that something is accessible through the _SERVER super global and not through the usually more secure `filter_input()`. I can't think of a valid reason for this behaviour either.